# Why is my aws elastic beanstalk listener path-based forward rule not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 2 "forward to" rules on an HTTP port 80 listener (see image). If a browser requests http://{domain}/health or  http://{domain}/health/, these rules are supposed to forward traffic to the target group at the current port.

If they don't, traffic should be redirected to the HTTPS port 443.

[image: My rules are similar to that of the guide]

Unfortunately, requesting /health/ or /health still sends me down the https 443 port. This is causing issues for the ELB health checker (described more in this guide https://medium.com/@Pibastte/how-to-setup-http-to-https-redirection-for-a-django-application-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-have-de44cf05565). My rules are exactly the same as in that guide*.

So what's going on? Any help is appreciated :)

*Edit: Woop I just realized that I forgot to mention that I rigorously tried paths both with and without the asterisk at the beginning.

Comment: The rules are correct. I think there is something wrong with the query you are using to test. Can you do `curl -i http://{domain}/health` and double check the output?

Comment: curl -i http://{domain}/health returns an empty reponse with an HTTP 301 permanently moved.
curl -i http://{domain}/health/ returns an HTML page showing that all the checks have passed. The HTTP status is 200. I believe this is redirecting to https:// because that's what happens in the browser.

Comment: The first one (301) is redirection. The second one is regular http.

Comment: By the way, browser can force redirection. I think chrome is doing this by default. So check with curl is always better.

Comment: You're right. I changed the rules to return a fixed response and they seem to be working. I've misidentified the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Sure. Go ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The listener
rules are **correct**. The rules were verified using:

```
curl -i http://{domain}/health/
```

which returned **HTTP 200**, rather then HTTP 301 (redirection), as expected.

It also should be noted, that browsers can force `http` to `https` redirection. Thus its always better to check any HTTP requests using `curl`.